# sorted atomic linked list algorithm (priority queue)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Can somebody point me towards an algorithm for a sorted thread-safe atomic (lock-free) linked list/priority queue? I'm aware of how to do just a linked list itself, but now I need one that is sorted. I'm unsure if this is minor change or significant redesign compared to an unsorted list, thus would like to see an existing algorithm before I make my own.

It needn't actually be a list (or technically sorted), but behaves like a priority queue with these properties:

- *lowest element* is the one with the minimum integer field value
- access to *lowest element* in constant time
- modification via atomic operations only (no locks)
- insertion/removal in linear time

The contents will likely be pointers to structures. The integer field to sort is one of the members of that structure.

This is for a C++ program, but I don't need code examples, an algorithm description is fine. Algorithms which come close, but not perfect, are also appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you want an atomic priority queue if you just need the minimum element.  This is still an interesting question, though, and I'm curious what the answer is.

Comment: Yes, priority queue is probably closer to what I logically want. I've updated the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this: "[Fast and Lock-Free Concurrent Priority Queues for
Multi-Thread Systems](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.679)". Googling will give you more links for sure.

Comment: Was about to post that article to. More direct link: http://www.adm.hb.se/~hsu/TechnicalReports/SunT03_PQueue.pdf